# Mongo project child object but with fewer props

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mapreduce

I have a simple document like this in my Collection named 'Partners'

```
[{
PartnerName: 'Company A',
MarketExpertese: [{Sector: {Code: 1, TotalYears: 1, TotalMonths: 20, TotalClients: 10}},
{Sector: {Code: 2, TotalYears: 2, TotalMonths: 20, TotalClients: 10}},
{Sector: {Code: 3, TotalYears: 3, TotalMonths: 20, TotalClients: 10}}]
}]
```

The result of desired projection would be:

```
[{
PartnerName: 'Company A',
MarketExpertese: [{SectorCode: 1, TotalYears: 1},
{SectorCode: 2, TotalYears: 2},
{SectorCode: 3, TotalYears: 3}]
}]
```

I tried the projection with Map but didn´t work. If I would need just an array of SectorCode (simple array, ex. `{[1, 2, 3]}` ) I could do, but as I need a prop with 2 values (sectorCode and TotalYears) my map fails...

The closet I could get was this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZxA6ITEC_Sw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need to use `$unwind` to get a stream of documents regarding the array `MarketExpertese`, each document will have an element from that array

then use the `$project` stage to format the output as we need

then use `$group` to group the documents we have unwind in first step

the query may look something like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$MarketExpertese" // First we need to use unwind to get a stream of documents regarding this array, each document will have only one element from that array
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      PartnerName: 1,
      Taste: {
        SectorCode: "$MarketExpertese.Sector.Code",
        TotalYears: "$MarketExpertese.Sector.TotalYears"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": { // then group the results
      "_id": "$_id",
      PartenerName: {
        "$first": "$PartnerName"
      },
      Taste: {
        "$addToSet": "$Taste"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

and here is a working example on [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zuR02b6iqqB)

---

### Update

you can use $map to do the same functionality

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "PartnerName": 1,
      "Teste": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$MarketExpertese",
          "as": "elem",
          "in": {
            SectorCode: "$$elem.Sector.Code",
            TotalYears: "$$elem.Sector.TotalYears",
            
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

and you can test it here [Mongo Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aZBEPjuEZXg)

Comment: MarketExpertese is a prop and not a collection name...

Comment: oh sorry I misunderstood the question, I've updated my answer to match your requirements, could you check it again?

Comment: Worked fine now, thanks! I was wondering, would have another way using map? The example I used has just few props, but in my system I have like 20, sou the group would be a little painfull... cheers

Comment: yes you can use $map, I've updated my answer again, could you check it?